# oracle sql DEVELOPER ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.2.15.21 and I want to debug a PROCEDURE. I am unable to do this as I get the following error message...

Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '192.168.1.88', '54159' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

In SQLDeveloper go to 'Tools' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Debugger'
Click the option for 'Prompt for debugger host for database debugging'

Comment: A precision, you have to enter the hostname of the machine which execute the debugger not the hostname of the database server. If you have ACL on your database instance, you need to add the hostname of the debugger machine in.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. The source of the problem was the local firewall that block the connection back from the database server (windows 7).

To solve it I authorized SqlDevelopper to communicate through Windows Firewall.

- Control Pannel\ Security .. \Firewall\ Authorized programs to communicate ...

The path for Windows French version is
Panneau de configuration\Système et sécurité\Pare-feu Windows\Programmes autorisés

- In the programs' list search for sqldeveloper (**sqldeveloper64w** in my configuration) check on the corresponding network (private and or public).

For further details I suggest to read the following article  :[failure establishing connection to debugger tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_30683_failure_establishing_connection_to_debugger.htm)